# Checking text for an approximate match

Tags: iphone, ios, string, ipad, sqlite

I am working on Sqlite and I have added some questions and answers data. I am matching that data in a textfield. When I type the correct answer it's working fine, but what about approximately correct answers? I don't know how to do it.

Example: If I type CORRECT then if it matches, it works fine. But...

If I type CORRET, then it has to show "Answer is approximarely correct"

How to solve this? Can anyone help me. And I am matching Data from Sqlite.

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the data from coredata with this code  and compare with the textfield data as;

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate =  (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MileageTrack" inManagedObjectContext:context]; //Where MileageTrack is my coredata entity
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    int i=0;

    NSError *error;

    NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    for (MileageTrack *info1 in objects) {

        NSMutableDictionary *dict1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [dict1 setObject:info1.tripusage forKey:@"answer"];
if([[dict1 objectForKey:@"answer"] isEqualToString:textfield.text])
{
NSLog(@"correct answer");

}
else
{
NSLog(@"wrong answer");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This following sqlite command can help you.

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:"select username from tblData where name is %%@%",name];
```

this command will bring all your data, 
like, 
if you type "correct"
it will take 1correct, 2correct, anycorrect, correctany.

if it doesn't word try with %%;

Comment: I am able to fetch data from Sqlite but my issue is I am not getting Approximate Answer Eg: As your name is Junaid then its working but if i mistaken in spell like Junad so i should get approximate answer can u help me ?

Comment: this can be solve using the wildCards, check this link, it will help you. http://sqlite.awardspace.info/syntax/sqlitepg03.htm